# Collision tests not working in SpriteKit Swift 2

Tags: sprite-kit, swift2, collision-detection

I have been trying to figure out why my     `didBeginContact` method isn't working. I have a triangle falling from the top of the screen to the bottom and I have a line at the bottom which if it collides with it. My score should increment. 
Here is the code responsible for this.

```
func createScene(){

    physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

    slider = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Slider")
    slider.setScale(0.20)
    slider.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: 0 + slider.frame.height / 2)


    slider.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: slider.size)
    slider.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCatergory.slider
    slider.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCatergory.coin | PhysicsCatergory.greenTriangle | PhysicsCatergory.orangeHexagon | PhysicsCatergory.purpleOctagon | PhysicsCatergory.redSquare
    slider.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCatergory.coin | PhysicsCatergory.greenTriangle | PhysicsCatergory.orangeHexagon | PhysicsCatergory.purpleOctagon | PhysicsCatergory.redSquare
    slider.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    slider.physicsBody?.dynamic = false

    var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: Selector("SpawnShapes"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    self.addChild(slider)


}

func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    let firstBody = contact.bodyA
    let secondBody = contact.bodyB

    if firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatergory.greenTriangle && secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatergory.Score{
        score++
        print(score)

    }
    else if firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatergory.Score && secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatergory.greenTriangle{
        score++
        print(score)
    }



}

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        createScene()
    invisibleBounderies()


}

func invisibleBounderies(){

    let scoreNode = SKSpriteNode()
    scoreNode.size = CGSize(width: 5, height: 600)
    scoreNode.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height / 10)
    scoreNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: scoreNode.size)
    scoreNode.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    scoreNode.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    scoreNode.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCatergory.Score
    scoreNode.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCatergory.greenTriangle
    scoreNode.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCatergory.greenTriangle
    scoreNode.zRotation = CGFloat(M_PI/2.0)
    scoreNode.color = SKColor.blueColor()


    self.addChild(scoreNode)



}



func SpawnShapes(){

    greenTriangle = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"greenTriangle")
    purpleOctagon = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "purpleOctagon")
    redSquare = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "redSquare")
    coin = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "coin")

    greenTriangle.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: greenTriangle.size)
    greenTriangle.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 0
    greenTriangle.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCatergory.Score
    greenTriangle.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCatergory.Score
    greenTriangle.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    greenTriangle.physicsBody?.dynamic = false

    var MinValue = self.size.width / 8
    var MaxValue = self.size.width - 150
    var SpawnPoint = UInt32(MaxValue - MinValue)

    let action = SKAction.moveToY(-30, duration: 2.0)


    slider.zPosition = 1
    coin.zPosition = 2
    greenTriangle.zPosition = 3
    orangeHexagon.zPosition = 4
    purpleOctagon.zPosition = 5
    redSquare.zPosition = 6



    greenTriangle.position = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(SpawnPoint)), y: self.size.height)
    self.addChild(greenTriangle)
    greenTriangle.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(action))



}
```

Answer (score 1):

- You need to set only `greenTriangle` `dynamic` property to `true`.
- You set `greenTriangle.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 0`, that's why you are not detecting contact. `greenTriangle.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCatergory.greenTriangle` might do the trick.

If you are still not detecting contact after these changes, check if your `physicsCatergory` is alright. It would be good to implement an `enum` of type `UInt32` where the values are all single bits, or like this, if you prefer:

```
enum PhysicsCatergory : UInt32{
    case slider = 1
    case coin = 2
    case greenTriangle = 4
    case purpleOctagon = 8
    case redSquare = 16
    case orangeHexagon = 32
    case Score = 64
}
```

Doing like this will require to add `.rawValue` in every reference to one of these enums. Example: `greenTriangle.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCatergory.greenTriangle.rawValue`

I know it is not related to the question, but I would recommend you not to use `SKAction` for movement in this case, because it's going to ignore physics collision, since you are  "forcing" its position. Use the `physicsBody.velocity` property instead to let the physics work. You will notice that when using the later the block is going to collide with the score line, since you also set its `collisionBitMask`. This way you can properly control with that it collides. Set `physicsBody.linearDamping` to zero if don't want the block to lose speed while it travels (air friction).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I meant to assign the     `categoryBitMask` to its `PhysicsCatergory` but I made an error which I didn't mean to. I am new to game development so I don't know a whole lot thank you for the extra tips I will add the changes you suggested to the program :) @Pietro Pepe

Comment: and for the objects I did this     
    `struct PhysicsCatergory {
         static let slider : UInt32 = 0x1 << 1
         static let coin : UInt32 = 0x1 << 2
         static let greenTriangle : UInt32 = 0x1 << 3
         static let orangeHexagon : UInt32 = 0x1 << 4
         static let purpleOctagon : UInt32 = 0x1 << 5
         static let redSquare : UInt32 = 0x1 << 6
         static let Wall : UInt32 = 0x1 << 7
         static let Score : UInt32 = 0x1 << 8
     
     }
`

Comment: You are welcome, feel free to link me any other problems you might have. This struct you implemented is alright. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks when I do I will let you know thanks a lot @Pietro Pepe

Answer (score 0):

A physicsBody with a `dynamic` property of `false` cannot be involved in collisions; set `dynamic` to true`.`

Comment: for all things that have to do with collisions?

Comment: I did change the dynamic properties of `greenTriangle` and `scoreNode` equal to true and the score is not incrementing. and when the greenTriangle  hits the scoreNode line it lags over it.

Comment: @SteveIves, non dynamic items can have physics tests done on them,  They just can't invoke physics calls.